# Delphi equivalent to VB's "DirectCast"?

Tags: vb.net, delphi

in VB.Net you have the "DirectCast" to send mousesclicks or other events to an other DirectX Application.

Is there a equivalent to this in Delphi? Or any other useful way to go?

```
        Public Sub ClickToL(ByVal WindowHandle As IntPtr, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer)
        Dim num As Integer = Me.MakeLong(X, Y)
        Form1.SendMessage(WindowHandle, DirectCast(&H201, IntPtr), IntPtr.Zero, DirectCast(num, IntPtr))
        Form1.SendMessage(WindowHandle, DirectCast(&H202, IntPtr), IntPtr.Zero, DirectCast(num, IntPtr))
    End Sub
```

this sample sends a mouse click to a minimized application (DirectX)

Comment: [`DirectCast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x.aspx) appears cast an object to a different type. I can't see how that relates to dispatching mouse events. Please elaborate with an example.

Comment: edited my question for a sample

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a cast to call SendMessage:

```
SendMessage(WindowHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, MakeLong(X, Y));
SendMessage(WindowHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, MakeLong(X, Y));
```

For what it is worth, your VB.net code incorrectly declares the second parameter to SendMessage as IntPtr. It should be an unsigned 32 bit integer.

If you do need need to implement a cast in Delphi, from one type to another you have two choices. An unchecked cast,

```
X := SomeType(Y);
```

which casts Y to be of type SomeType without runtime checks. Or a checked cast,

```
X := Y as SomeClass;
```

which will raise an exception is Y is not SomeClass.

Answer (score 2):

The Delphi equivalent of `DirectCast` would be a type cast.

For example casting a reference varaible to the class `Form`:

```
VB:      DirectCast(myRef, Form)

Deplhi:  Form(myRef)
```